# Content Encoding Error using Visual Composer 5.4.5

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

I am using visual composer latest version 5.4.5 in my wordpress site. When i have transfer site in live server then admin side after edit any page, page content and VC page builder not display and after little loading display this error -> http://nimb.ws/nT6Lco

I have also changed my server php version but error not fixed. So any one know solutions for this then please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Add following line at end of your .htaccess file and issues fixed.

**SubstituteMaxLineLength 100m**

After add above line all visual composer features work good.